# Will a broken screen harm my laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, power-supply, power

My laptop fell on the ground and its screen cracked. Everything works perfectly except of course the broken screen. I ordered a new one already.

My concern is that, because of these large dark areas, it may harm the powering system somehow... may cause some power leakage of some kind, or affect the screen cable or the screen socket.

My question is that if I continue working with my laptop for a few days, ***will it harm my laptop in anyway?***

[image]

Comment: No, I don't see real chance for the screen to harm any other part of the laptop. However it's difficult to use with so big dark areas, you may want to  use it with an external display until the replacement arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no reason to be concerned of. A broken screen has nothing to do with any other components of the laptop. It also won't affect the powering system. Just wait for your new screen to arrive and you can use the laptop till then without worrying anything.

However using this laptop may affect your eyes as I can see the condition of your screen from the attached image. It could be better if you use a second monitor till the new ones.

Thank you.